# TSQL error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have searched through SO, but not found anything to help resolve my issue. I am not sure how to interpret the error message with regards to my query.

My query is:

```
select AST_ID,
    case  when CRA_StatusID=1 then 'Wait on Info'
    when CRA_StatusID=2 then 'Wait PrePay'
    when CRA_StatusID=3 then 'Acquire Chart'
    when CRA_StatusID=4 then 'Copy Chart'
    when CRA_StatusID=5 then 'Need Invoice'
    when CRA_StatusID=6 then 'Wait Payment'
    when CRA_StatusID=7 then 'Ready for Delv' else 'Complete' end as AST_Status,
    case when AST_WOPrinted is null then '' else 'Y' end as AST_WOPrinted,
    case when AST_DeliveryDate is null then '' else 'Y' end as AST_Delivered,
    AST_PatientLName+'', ''+AST_PatientFName+' '+AST_PatientMName as PatientName,
    case when len(AST_RequestorName) > 0 then AST_RequestorName else AST_RequestorContact end as AST_RequestorName,
    AST_Created,AST_ProviderName
    from dbo.AST
    inner join dbo.fnASTCurrentStatus() on AST_ID=CRA_ASTID
    where ' + @WhereClause + '

    union all
    select AST_ID,
    case 
    when CRA_StatusID=1 then 'Wait on Info'
    when CRA_StatusID=2 then 'Wait PrePmt'
    when CRA_StatusID=3 then 'Aquire Chart'
    when CRA_StatusID=4 then 'Copy Chart'
    when CRA_StatusID=5 then 'Need Invc'
    when CRA_StatusID=6 then 'Wait Pmt'
    when CRA_StatusID=7 then 'Ready for Delv' else 'Complete'
    end as AST_Status,
    case when AST_WOPrinted is null then '' else 'Y' end as AST_WOPrinted,
    case when AST_DeliveryDate is null then '' else 'Y' end as AST_Delivered,
    AST_PatientLName+'', ''+AST_PatientFName+' '+AST_PatientMName as PatientName,
    case when len(AST_RequestorName) > 0 then AST_RequestorName else AST_RequestorContact end as AST_RequestorName,
    AST_Created,AST_ProviderName
    from dbo.Archive_AST 
    inner join dbo.fnArchiveASTCurrentStatus() on AST_ID=CRA_ASTID
    where ' + @WhereClause + '  



set @WhereClause=' AST_ProviderID in (select ProviderID from dbo.UserProvider where CSA_UserID = ' + convert(varchar,55) + ')'
```

error message reads:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'union'.
>
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near ' + @WhereClause + '.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: ` where ' + @WhereClause + ' ` is not a valid where clause..?

Comment: the @whereClause is defined separately within the stored procedure.

Comment: what is the value of @where? just an example so we can understand what it looks like. But yes thebjorn is correct your where clause is invalid

Comment: set needs to be above select

Comment: Does that `where` change all the time or is it only the user ID that changes? You are doing dynamic sql but not correctly. You could change the whole query to a string to concatenate @whereclause and then exec the whole string. But maybe dynamic sql isn't what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: The whereclause changes based upon Permissions for UserID value. The WhereClause is either '' or ' AST_ProviderID in (select ProviderID from dbo.UserProvider where CSA_UserID = ' + convert(varchar,55) + ')'

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that this way. You are mixing a plain SQL Query with dynamic SQL. You must choose if you use or not dynamic SQL. If you do so, check the `EXECUTE` keyword or `sp_executesql` system Stored Procedure.

If it's dynamic SQL, your where clause variable should happen **before** building the query.

You query can easily be written like this :

Keep the whole query up to the WHERE clause and

```
...
WHERE AST_ProviderID in (select ProviderID from dbo.UserProvider where CSA_UserID = convert(varchar,55))
```

If you want, you can also use a variable or a parametrized query :

```
DECLARE @myvar INT = 55;
...
WHERE AST_ProviderID in (select ProviderID from dbo.UserProvider where CSA_UserID = convert(varchar, @myvar))
```

Comment: The query is dynamic sql. I converted it to regular sql to post on SO, just to make it easier to understand

Comment: @user3929962 Your error message refers to where you are constructing your SQL, not where you are executing it. You haven't converted it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on other responses, you should do a `Print @WhereClause` and see how the output is formatted, but it's definitely the `@whereclause` causing the issue